# I have an Oracle database 10g installed on my server, off late the system.dbf file in the SYSTEM tablespace is filling up very quicky

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I have an Oracle database 10g installed on my server, off late, the **system.dbf** file in the SYSTEM tablespace is filling up very quicky. System01.dbf file filled up (32Gb size) completely in 10 years, then this year on May, we created system02.dbf file but it filled up so fast and it is full within 3 months. Now we created another system03.dbf file and everyday it fills up almost 1GB of space. This way I will run out of space within a few days. Any help will be appreciated. I am really new to Oracle database administration.

Comment: 10g is very old and no longer supported. Apart from that, you need to work out **WHY** your system tablespace is filling up. No-one should be creating tables in the system tablespace so your first thing to do is work out who is using it and get them to stop and migrate to their own user. Then you need to work out why they are creating so much data. We cannot help you with that (you haven't given us enough information and, regardless, its off-topic for StackOverflow).

Comment: what information do you need? I will post you all the required info. Yes 10g is very old and situation is such that we cannot upgrade it. Many many applications are running on it.

Comment: How can I see WHY it is filling up so quickly.... any database query that would help me find out why it is filling so fast?

Comment: Have you recently changed any auditing settings? Check views like DBA_SEGMENTS to see what is using up the space.

Comment: not sure but I believe my predecessors do not change things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can check objects inside tablespace 'SYSTEM'.
For example SQL  Top 10 large objects in `tablespace_name='SYSTEM'`

```
select * from (select owner,
                      segment_name, 
                      segment_type, 
                      bytes/1024/1024 mb 
                 from dba_segments 
                where tablespace_name='SYSTEM'
                order by bytes/1024/1024 desc) 
 where rownum <= 10;
```

Comment: I would have posted a screenshot but I see no option to upload image. The query above gives me 2 rows namely AUD$ with 52558MB size and I AUD1 with 17487MB size

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sys_aud.htm

Comment: appreciate your help, I will look into the document (link) and post further queries or actions that we take with our system.

Comment: For now we have decided to stop any audit that's happening in the system using this command.

"ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trail=none SCOPE=SPFILE;"

But eventually we would like our system to be recording the audit of users in the system. Right now it is recording unnecessary things so we stopped temporarily.

Comment: After changing the audit parameter, the parameter changed only in the config file pfile'SCOPE=SPFILE'.  You need to restart the instance to apply the setting.
https://itoporacledba.com/script/how-to-enable-disable-standard-audit-trail-on-oracle-database-10g-onward/

Answer (score 0):

we have stopped the audit trail as we do not need it. There are no further filling up of space. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Rather than post this as an answer, would you be able to edit your question to include this as an update to it?